# Dexie DB: How to save an array to a database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, web, save, dexie

The database has the [toArray](http://dexie.org/docs/Collection/Collection.toArray()) method, how to save the array to the database (toDB)?

Comment: I don't think it returns a stored array. It puts a collection of items into an array. The reverse operation would possibly be [`Table.bulkAdd()`](http://dexie.org/docs/Table/Table.bulkAdd().html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Table.bulkAdd() or Table.bulkPut(). For example:

```
var db = new Dexie("testdb");
db.version(1).stores({friends: 'id,name,age'});
db.friends.bulkPut([
    {id: 1, name: "Foo", age: 33},
    {id: 2, name: "Bar", age: 34}
]).then(result => {
    alert ("Successfully stored the array");
}).catch(error => {
    alert ("Error: " + error);
});
```

Comment: nice. we had a for loop setting up 100s of objects and it was eating the CPU alive for the first initial min. this completely resolved that. thx